# React-Native-FlatList: onEndReached not working with customed CellRendererComponent

Tags: react-native, z-index, react-native-flatlist, cellrenderer

### Description

One of the `FlatList`'s well-known bugs is probably about `zIndex`.

I'm working on drag and drop cards in `FlatList`, but `zIndex` doesn't work as expected.

So I customize CellRenderComponent as workaround(see [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18616#issuecomment-389444165)), but when I use CellRenderComponent, `onEndReached` doesn't work properly on real device.

Try my [Sample Project](https://snack.expo.io/@seunghyunwoo/strange-flatlist) to see how it acts.

### React Native version:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.4
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz
    Memory: 1.94 GB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.16.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.5, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 23.0.1, 28.0.3, 29.0.3
      System Images: android-23 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-23 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548
    Xcode: 11.5/11E608c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

### Steps To Reproduce

Provide a detailed list of steps that reproduce the issue.

1. Having problem with `zIndex` in a list
2. Customize `CellRendererComponent`
3. Now `onEndReached` working weird.

### Expected Results

FlatList should call `onEndReached` and load more cards when scroll reaches to the end, but it seems to call `onEndReached` at weird point and jump right to the end.

### Snack, code example, screenshot, or link to a repository:

[This is my sample project](https://snack.expo.io/@seunghyunwoo/strange-flatlist)

Please don't hesitate to correct me: I'm quite new to react-native.
Thank you in advance.